# Having issues creating foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have a table called member:

```
create table member(id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(255) NOt NULL, email varchar(255) NOT NULL, userName varchar(255) 
NOT NULL, password varchar(255) NOT NULL, handicap int);
```

and trying to create a table `stableford` which will have a foreign key name from the `member` table:

create table stableford(id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, title varchar(255) NOT NULL, player_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
score int NOT NULL, INDEX(player_name), FOREIGN KEY(player_name) REFERENCES member(name));

Name of database is `golfclub`

> I get an error cant create table 'golfclub.#sql-d1c_6' (errno:150)

Comment: You ought to use the parent table's PK as the FK in the child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the id on the member table as the foreign key and would be better to change it to something like `membber_id`. Here are references to help:
[W3Schools foreign key constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 1):

> A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

The error you are getting is because of following reasons:

1. The column `name` of table `member` you have referenced is not a `primary key`. So for adding a `foreign key` you have to reference the `primary key` of the referenced table which is `id` in this case. Go through this the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).
2. Syntax Error: You are missing the closing `)` of second create statement.